# Magento2.3 Payment Gateway Extension

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I tried to develop a simple payment gateway extension for Magento 2.3.x and above. It required to support bank hosted method only. When user click place order leads to bank payment page and the card details enter only in the bank payment gateway page. How can I set up this with bank payment page URL and custom parameters to pass this gateway page?

In where I can set the third-party payment gateway URL, etc in Magento 2 gateway methods?

Comment: Do you want to create custom redirect payment methods?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya
I required to create a payment method with third-party bank payment gateway. When customer click place order after selecting the payment method, navigate to bank page and customers can enter card details in there.

Comment: Have you implement anything or not?

Comment: I am trying to implement with afterplaceholder () to redirect html form (auto submit this form) to bank payment page